# how to align this items at center?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Do you know how  to align at center the the text  `"value1", "value2", "value3"` relative to the text above `"Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"`. The `"value1", "value2" and "value3"` appear a bit at right relative to `"Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"`. Its like a table layout but without using tables.

Working example:https://jsfiddle.net/teydLt4t/4/

**html:**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card_body">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 1</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 2</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 3</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span class="font-size-sm">Description type</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">value</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">value</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">value</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div>
          <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Description</span>
        </div>
        <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-lg text-heading-blue">value</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want multiple rows to display items in a column coordinated fashion you have two options:

- use `<table>` elements
- control the width of your cells

I'd use `flex-grow:1` in conjunction with `flex-basis:0%`:

```css
.list-group-item > span {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.list-group-item > span {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card_body">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Title</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 2 - this is a longer text let's see if it wraps</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 3</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span class="font-size-sm">Description</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">valu2</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">value3</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">value4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        
        <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Description</span>
        
        <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-lg text-heading-blue">value</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Updated example (as per comments):

```css
.list-group-item > span {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 25%;
}
.list-group-item > span:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: center;
}

.list-group-item {
  justify-content: space-betwen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card_body">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Title</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 2 - this is a longer text let's see if it wraps</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 3</span>
        <span class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span class="font-size-sm">Description</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">valu2</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">value3</span>
        <span class="font-size-sm">value4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        
        <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Description</span>
        
        <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-lg text-heading-blue">value</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to put the bold text "value" aligned at the right? And if its possible that the content occupies the full width but aligned at center. For example there is less space at left of the text "Title" than the right space of "Item 4" and "value 4", there is much more space at right of "Item 4" then the left space of "Title".

Comment: @JohnZ, in principle, I don't agree with adding requirements to the question after the original request was answered. Also note you're supposed to put in some research effort yourself before asking. In order to achieve what you want, you'd need to limit the width of the cells, using `max-width` and also control their `text-align` property. If you limit `max-width` to `25%` for cells, you'll need `justify-content:space-between;` on parent row for last row. I added a second example to illustrate the above. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to the titles and a width in css.

```
.title {
  width: 100px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teydLt4t/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The alignment issue is coming because of the different length of text. So fix the span element width, so that it will align everything properly.

```
  li.list-group-item span {width:25%;}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/teydLt4t/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**Table**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) instead for this layout.

```css
table.table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">

  <div class="card_body">
    <table class=" table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><span class="font-weight-bold">Title</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="">
          <td class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Title</td>
          <td class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 2</td>
          <td class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 3</td>
          <td class="text-heading-blue font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Item 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td class="font-size-sm">Description</td>
          <td class="font-size-sm">valu2</td>
          <td class="font-size-sm">value3</td>
          <td class="font-size-sm">value4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td colspan="3">
            <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Description</span>
          </td>
          <td class="font-weight-bold font-size-lg text-heading-blue">value</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using <table> as tags you can also work with display: table; display: table-row; and display: table-cell; this is often more usefull if it needs to be responsive

Comment: @MarcelSchmid, please show us how to use `colspan` with `display:table`. It's way easier to enforce `display:block` on `<table>` elements, IMHO, if you really need responsive behavior. It's still hackish and feels wrong, but it works, cross-browser/cross-device.

Comment: True, colspan is not possible, forgot about this. I just prefer this way, when i have same sized columns.

Comment: @MarcelSchmid rather than using `display:table` you should consider `display:grid` for layout. I try to limit `display:table` at tabular data, when `<table>` is not an option. But, from experience, `<table>` has better browser support and creates less problems than `display:table`. The only real problem with it is it's extremely expensive in terms of rendering.